# Как получить доступ к страницам navigationPage NavigationFrame

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress

**Используется**
Visual Studio 2015;
Devexpress 17.1.5.

Когда нажимаю на пространство NavigationFrame на WinForms 
выделяется navigationPage.

Чтобы переключиться в NavigationFrame мне нужно выбрать NavigationFrame  в Свойствах

**Вопрос**
Как или куда мне нужно нажать на WinForms чтобы выделилось NavigationFrame?
Или есть другой способ как получить доступ к коллекции страниц?

Скрин

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Непонятно что во что вложено.

Предлагаю три варианта для общего случая:

1. Нажать правой кнопкой мыши по компоненту. В выпадающем меню должны появиться пункты «Выбрать navigationFrame1», «Выбрать navigationPage2» и т.д. в зависимости от количества уровней вложенности. Выберите нужный компонент.
2. Отобразите в Visual Studio окно «Document Outline» («Структура документа»). В окне отображается дерево компонентов текущей формы. Возможно это более удобное представление для Вашего случая. Показать окно можно в меню «View -> Other Windows -> Document Outline» (может отличаться в зависимости от локализации и версии среды)
3. Способ №3:

   - кликнуть по **navigationPage**;
   - кликнуть по полю **Visual Studio** (рядом c **Form**);
   - нажать `ESC`;

В результате появляется меню **navigationFrame**.

Comment: `Непонятно что во что вложено` -  Я просто взял `NavigationFrame` в `toolbox` и вытащил на `WinForm`. Что вы имеете ввиду? Или `NavigationFrame` нужно размещать на определённом элементе?

Comment: @koverflow это и было непонятно. Неясно идеть ли речь о страницах того же самого фрейма или фрейм сам вложен в чужую страницу.

Comment: Не.. фрейм один на ВинФорм. **1.*** п.2 сработал. **недостаток:** нет поля для поиска. Если будет много элементов, то хлопотно будет искать нужный элемент. **2.***  А п.1  не понял...  Вы имели ввиду если фрейм вложен во что-то? скрин http://prntscr.com/g6b47e

Comment: @koverflow п. 2 Да, неудобно, хорошо хоть узлы можно сворачивать/разворачивать. п.1. Да, это и имел ввиду.

Comment: Дополнил ваш ответ. Если вы не против. Проверьте.